# friction between 2 bodies

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, friction

***There is a plank on which a block is kept. the block is given some velocity. Now if there is friction between block and plank it will act opposite to it's velocity for sure. but the plank is free to move. so where will the friction for the plank act? also if plank and block are the system is friction an internal force?? in other words will their centre of mass move??***

Comment: i am not asking a whole question damnitt !! i am confirming a conceptual doubt........losers who vote down should understand......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely, friction is an internal force but that does not mean that it won't cause any motion. Friction may not produce any motion in some cases but in certain cases it does.

The friction on the plank will act due to that by the block as shown below,
[image: Block and plank frictional force diagram]

As you can see, the plank is applying a frictional force on the block in the forward direction (which tends to move it). Simultaneously, the block is also applying an equal amount of frictional force on the plank in the opposite direction.

Now I will answer your last question. In those cases, in which the friction is not enough to make the block move (consider the pseudo force that acts in the backward direction and hence opposite to the friction), the block will simply fall off the back side and the plank will keep moving on its own and the block will keep moving in the opposite direction (of course, considering that the bottom plane is smooth). In this case the center of mass will not move.

But in case the block moves along with the plank, the center of mass will of course move.

Hope I could make it clear enough. If you have anything that needs clarification, please add it in comments.

Comment: In both cases the center of mass of the plank and the block will move with the same velocity, due to conservation of momentum.